# What do you call that section in a CMS where you just add a data list?

Tags: terminology, data, cms

**In our CMS there are 3 main sections:**

1. Dashboard
2. Section for adding data that will appear in the app (e.g. users, products, location, etc.)
3. Tasks (e.g. approving comments, etc.)

I'm not sure how to call **#2** because I'd like to put headers for the sections. I am thinking 'data list' but it sounds a bit dry. Is there a more appropriate term for it?

Comment: Wouldn't #2 come under "Dashboard"? And then name it what it is: Users, Products, Location, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

"Content" is one option, "Body Content" is another.

Comment: "Content" sounds good.

Comment: Now I've re-read my answer, I agree with Alvaro, "Body Content" seems to lean towards web dev, unless users are used to that term, I'd avoid it.

Comment: "Content" sounds good.. although I feel that I can't park "Users" under that one. Should "Users" be its own section?

Answer (score 1):

**Content** is indeed a good choice, at least for us who come from development/design background, because it makes sense the way we architect the backend, in the end they are all models.

But Users might not always agree, if i were you i would make **[Open Card Sorting](https://www.usability.gov/how-to-and-tools/methods/card-sorting.html)** by a sample from the market and let them design the architecture of your information, so that it makes more sense for people in their background.

Comment: Upvote for Card Sorting!

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to find it online but my last company used to describe it as Portal, if I remember right and had separate **Content portal** and **User portal**. T

Also, I believe the term Portal defined a lot more than just Content and User( as the meaning also implies) and specific areas were called Content Portal and User Portal etc.

Answer (score 0):

What about **Add New** or similar to it.

The purpose of this section is to add some new data object to the application, therefore it would be more useful if you name this section by the intended use of it, i.e. creating new data objects.